# simple way to draw a line segment with Python

Tags: python, math, graphics

I work in a High School Math Department. I am looking at replacing the current programming language(TrueBASIC) with Python. The point in the students coding is to teach math, not programming. So we don't want them doing a LOT of coding for simple math concepts. TrueBASIC is fine but it is not supported.

My current stumbling block is drawing a line segment. I've found ways to draw them using separate lists of x and y values. That will be confusing for students who are just learning what a point is. Rearranging the values so much will cause problems.

The closest thing I've found is a function that will draw a line.

[How to draw a line with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470343/how-to-draw-a-line-with-matplotlib)

This is the first time I've used Python.

Comment: While it is commendable that you are looking to use programming in your class, this is not the correct platform for your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on what you are going to teach them, but [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) could be a good idea. Combine that with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and...