# Is there a way to mark the min and max of a line chart on its y axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a graph I've generated a little more useful in comparisons. Is there a way to make something like I've pictured below? Or possibly a way to draw a line across along the y value of the max and min?

I've tried using max() and min() and placing it in a plot like so:

```
plt.plot(dat[0]['end_date'], max(dat[0]['pct']))
```

Which throws a value error because the x list has something like 48 entries whereas the y list would only have one.

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (48,) and (1,)
```

Could I use some version of this that somehow fills the remaining 47 spaces with that same max value?

Thank you!

[image: Mentioned Above]

Comment: Yes.  Use this SO answer as an example to draw any line on a plot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479941/6067379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`plt.axhline()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline):

```
plt.axhline(max(dat[0]['pct']))
plt.axhline(min(dat[0]['pct']))
```

---

Demonstration using random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[np.random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]})
df.plot()
plt.axhline(df.x.max())
plt.axhline(df.x.min())
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding to you.