# how to join line among the points

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib

Hii experts i need to join the line between the points obtained using for loop .But only scatter plot(plt.scatter) is working not the plt.plot option in matplotlib

my prograamme is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=np.arange(1,5,1)

for i in f:
    sum = 0
    for m in np.arange(1,6,1):
        x=((4.6)*(m*2)*(5)**2)*(i)/62
        print(x)

        sum += x
    print(i,sum)
    plt.scatter(i,sum)
plt.show()
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470343/how-to-draw-a-line-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=np.arange(1,5,1)

x_values = []
y_values = []
for i in f:
    sum = 0
    for m in np.arange(1,6,1):
        x=((4.6)*(m*2)*(5)**2)*(i)/62
        
        sum += x
   
    #plt.scatter(i,sum)

    x_values.append(i)
    y_values.append(sum)


plt.plot(x_values, y_values, marker='o')
 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hii i want to save the x_values and y_values in a text file how can i do it

Comment: please suggest' sir...i am having problem on that

Comment: @glkshu can you comment on what you have tried?

Comment: @glkshu also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python

Comment: np.savetxt('file',x_values,y_values)

Comment: can u please  update the code so that i will be benificial

Comment: sir i am new to python so facing problem

Comment: please sir waiting for your reply