# add line segements between centroid and the cluster

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way in matplotlib to add line segments between each point in the cluster to its centroid?

I have a plot that looks like this:

[image]

and I want the result to look like this:
[image]

I have a two separate plots on top of each other. One with all the clusters and the other with the yellow centroids

Comment: This link should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470343/how-to-draw-a-line-with-matplotlib  or this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352580/matplotlib-plotting-numerous-disconnected-line-segments-with-different-colors

Comment: If you have the centroid coordinates and the points related to that centroid, you can do a simple `plt.plot([centroid_x, point_x], [centroid_y, point_y])` for every point you have, changing the colors as appropriate.